# Leaflet: Scroll wheel controlling map zoom and not drop down menu

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zoom, chrome, firefox

Edited 6/19/2015

I have a custom leaflet control box with a drop down menu.  When I use the scroll wheel over the menu, the map changes zoom level instead of scrolling the menu.  The problem occurs on IE and Firefox, but not Chrome.

How can I let the user operate the drop menus with their scroll wheel, when their cursor is over the menu?

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #map { height: 500px; }
            #legend { background: #FFF;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);

            var legend = L.control({position: "topright"});

            legend.onAdd = function (map) {
                var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend');
                div.innerHTML = '<h1>Title</h1><select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option><option>16</option><option>17</option><option>18</option><option>19</option><option>20</option><option>21</option><option>22</option><option>23</option><option>24</option><option>25</option><option>26</option><option>27</option><option>28</option><option>29</option><option>30</option><option>31</option><option>32</option><option>33</option><option>34</option><option>35</option><option>36</option><option>37</option><option>38</option><option>39</option><option>40</option></select>';
                div.firstChild.onmousedown = div.firstChild.ondblclick = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
                L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(div);
                return div;
            };
            legend.addTo(map);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is unlikely anyone can help you without seeing the code related to the custom control.

Comment: When trying this approach (from Kiikonen) it works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85461)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been stuck on an issue quite similar to yours by having a custom control with a scrollable div inside.

At least a partial solution can be achieved by using lines like this:

```
var elem = L.DomUtil.get('yourelementid');
L.DomEvent.on(elem, 'mousewheel', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
```

where `elem` is the element that's laid out over the map.

This prevents the map from being zoomed by scrolling the mouse wheel, but it is only a partial solution because it also prevents the scrolling inside the custom control. However, I'm not really sure how it acts on a dropdown like yours, so you might want to give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I had to add a new id to the parent div that contains the custom control I added.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to be of help! And yes, `L.DomUtil` is no jQuery, but does the trick :)